# Remove whitespace below picture in two column Word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm making a document with two columns. In my document I also want an image that covers two columns. The problem is that there is a whitespace I cannot get rid of:

[image: PICTURE]

How can I remove this whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have whitespace above the second column is because the two-column section is proceeded by a one-column section which contains some text that appears to be formatted with a very narrow right page margin:

[image]

You need to adjust the margin of that text to cover the width of the full page.

### Alternate Solution

Another approach would be to **move** the text immediately below your picture to the beginning of the two-column section of the document. This will result in all of the text after the graphic being organized into two columns, eliminating the whitespace below the picture.